# Python numpy loop index out of bounds error

Tags: arrays, for-loop, numpy, indexoutofboundsexception, python-3.2

```
a1 = np.random.random_sample(10)

a2 = np.random.random_sample(5)

a3 = np.zeros([10])


for i in range(0,9):

    a3[i] = ((a2[i]+a2[i+1])/2.) * ((a1[i+1]-a1[i])/2.) * (a1[i]*a2[i])

    print(i, a3[i])
```

I tried to run this simple script and I get the error `"IndexError: index out of bounds"` ...
Please any idea to avoid this error? I understand that the error caused by the number `5`,  but I can't change that as the `a2` array is loaded from a txt `(a2= np.loadtxt('data.txt',unpack=True, usecols=[1])` which its length is `5`
Please any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is only 5 elements in `a2`  because:

```
a2 = np.random.random_sample(5)
```

but in for loop runs for i > 5 upto 8

```
for i in range(0,9):

    a3[i] = ((a2[i]+a2[i+1])/2.) * ((a1[i+1]-a1[i])/2.) * (a1[i]*a2[i])
                       ^ index out                                ^ index out
```

because you access `a2` as `a2[i+1]` also. So `i` can be at most `3` try with `range(0,4)`

**EDIT**:

To fill five extra 1s do like:

```
a2.extend(5*[1])
a2
```

Comment: yes I know the problem... any idea what to do for make this script running? (adding zeros to a2, and increasing its length? )

Comment: @user1640255 Added an ides give it a try

Comment: I CANT change range(0,9)! ... and also in another part of my script the a2 has length 15, greater that others... whats then? Do I have add zeros to other arrays? Any other idea?

Comment: @user1640255 Yes increase `a2` size with `0` or `1` although I don't know what is your algo

Comment: any idea how to do that? is a secret?